# Asp.net file upload not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to upload file but getting an error The given path's format is not supported."

```
    string storageLocation = string.Empty;
    string newFile;

    switch (ddlDocType.SelectedItem.Text)
    {
        case "Letter":
            storageLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Letters/");
            break;
```

...

```
        if (filePosted.ContentLength > 0)
        {
                filePosted.SaveAs(Path.Combine( storageLocation , newFile));
        }
```

and also tried the following but still not working.

```
filePosted.SaveAs( storageLocation ,+ newFile);
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Debug the application and put a breakpoint as the file is about to be saved. If you perform Path.Combine(storageLocation, newFile) in the Immediate window what is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `newFile` is a file name like `newFile="myfile.rar";` then use this:

```
filePosted.SaveAs(storageLocation + newFile);
```

It seems you have an extra `,` near the `+`.

But if `newFile` is empty like the question's code, you should set a value before `.SaveAs`:

```
newFile = filePosted.FileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `newFile` is never given a value, so Path.Combine() is going to fail.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? With the information given, this is entirely accurate.

Comment: +1 - based on the snippet of code your answer is the probable cause.

Comment: newFile as value. I tried Response.Write(newFile) then I get the filename